# flutter app crashing after adding flutter_firebase_ui

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

When I added these two libraries my app is not working, it is showing close app dialog only

```
image_picker: 0.4.12+1 #^0.5.0+3
flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13
```

> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Built
>   build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk. Flutter is taking longer
>   than expected to report its views. Still trying...

After removing `flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13` my app works fine

 but in  my other project I am using  `flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13`
without 
 `image_picker: 0.4.12+1 #^0.5.0+3` and it is working fine.

 What is the issue?

```
Note: /home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.6.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/git/flutter_twitter_login-b28bcb56f7f86319a966dcf3a08543de358b1424/android/src/main/java/com/roughike/fluttertwitterlogin/fluttertwitterlogin/TwitterLoginPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

When i remove flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13 app work with out any problem

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on Lenovo K8 Plus in debug mode...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:706: error: cannot find symbol
  private void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:610: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.SignInCompleteListener
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:629: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.TaskVoidCompleteListener
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:647: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.GetSignInMethodsCompleteListener
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                              ^
  symbol: class NonNull
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NonNull
/home/midhilaj/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.8.1+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:559: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                          ^
  symbol: class NonNull
9 errors
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See "shorturl" for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: post the errors/stack you see in your debug console

Comment: wait i will update

Comment: @user969068 nothing is showing in debug console just showing class app dialog only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem SOlved by adding Facebook app id in AndroidManifest.xml 
Try run Android app with Android studio you will get the error message

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="adasdsa"/>
```

Comment: This helped! This is needed even if you do not use facebook login, which seems like a bug in the library!

Answer (score 2):

you need to choose the version the compatible with androidX 
see this link: [URL](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

you should use  firebase_auth: 0.7.0